# Query records which have been in a certain status for one hour or more

Tags: sql, oracle

So I have a question (running oracle sql developer), I can't seem to get the syntax of it right.

Let's say T1 has a `stat_code` column and a `last_updated` column; I want to query all records which have been in `t1.stat_code < 90` for one hour or more.

From research I have come with the following query;

```
select * from t1
where t1.stat_code <90
and t1.last_updated > (SYSDATE-1/24);
```

This is right, but also pulls back records which are less than an hour old.

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: I think you should use `t1.last_updated <= (SYSDATE-1/24)`

Answer (score 0):

You could also use an `INTERVAL` literal to explicitly state the duration:

```
SELECT *
FROM   t1
WHERE  stat_code    <  90
AND    last_updated <= SYSTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '1' HOUR;
```